# Showing Floor Button Controls with Google Maps Javascript API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So here's my issue: I'm writing a web-app using the Google Maps web API v3.  When zooming to a building that shows a floor-plan, the floor controls do not show up, as they do on Android.  When opening Google maps for Android, and zooming to the same building, I get a control on the bottom right-hand side of the screen that shows the floors (B1, 1, and 2), and selecting them shows that floor.  Not so using the web-API.  At first I thought it might be as simple as specifying which controls were visible/adding a control, but I'm not coming up with anything.

Does anyone else know how to get these buttons to show up?

**Note**: Even on Google's website (maps.google.com), in classic mode, these buttons do not show up when zoomed in on a Building with a floor plan, so maybe this is a lost cause...

[image: Google Maps Floor-Plan]

Comment: Do you have a handy google maps link to the location, or a location, so we can try to reproduce / debug?

Comment: @JECarterII Not anymore.  We switched to native maps awhile ago.

Comment: Understood.  If the question no longer needs to be answered, can you answer it yourself and mark the answer accepted?  That way nobody will find it sitting in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was requested to answer this question so that it's not sitting in the unanswered queue.

At the time this question was asked, Google Maps for web didn't support the floor buttons (to the best of my knowledge), so we moved to using the native SDK's on Android and iOS instead.

Comment: Do you have any idea when/if this feature will be added Google Maps JS v3?

Comment: @Charles I haven't the foggiest idea...sorry

Comment: These controls do show up on Google Maps Web UI now. Any updates on API access to these controls?